Need to see the track changes and comments of word document in view.officeapps.live.com/
I have a scenario where I want to preview the MS Word document in the web browser. Yes, I am able to do that. However, the problem here is that I am not able to view the track changes or the comments inside the Word document.
Here, view.officeapps.live.com is used to preview the document as shown below.
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=FILE_URL
example :
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx
Can anyone tell me how to enable the 'Track Changes' / 'Comments' view, or if it is not possible, an alternative view would be appreciated.
